# How to make a Theme apply for all the pages in the Portal?

Tags: liferay-6

I am new to Liferay , still trying to learn it .
so please excuse if this is a dumb question .

I have got different pages in my Portal (10-15 including child pages ) through which the user can navigate within the portal .

I have created my Own  Theme based on default welcome Theme , provided by Liferay 6.1 .

Now my question is that , for every page do i need to set the Page look and Feel to my own Theme ??

(I was asking this  , even though i navigated to )

**Liferay --> Control Panel --> Site Pages --> Look and Feel**

and selected Current Theme as my own theme , but my Theme is not showing for all the pages ??

Please tell me if there is any way i can select the Theme for all my Pages .

By the way i am using Liferay 6.1 version .

Thanks in advance .

Comment: I think you also have to also apply same theme for private pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally once you assigned theme to site pages[public and private pages] via
**Liferay --> Control Panel --> Site Pages --> Look and Feel**, it should be applied to all the pages of your site.

But in case if you have individually modified any particular page's Look and Feel [before step above], then it will retain old theme applied to it and you have to individually change it.

Hope this would help.